# Rails 3.2 modify params[] value on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following scenario where I have a datetime that I would like to reparse.  I can get the following to work in irb, but I seem to be having an issue with nil values when working with post parameters.  for ex.

This works in irb:

```
DateTime.strptime("10/25/2012 04:27 pm", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %P").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00")
=> "2012-10-25 16:27:00"
```

However when I try to access a params value I can't seem to access the value itself. for ex.

```
def create
  @shipment = params[:shipment]
  @shipment.ship_date = format_date(@shipment.ship_date)
  .
  .
  .
 end     

def format_date(date)
  DateTime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %P").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00")
end
```

When I set a variable manually with a string it works.  When I try to work off the parameter it seems to be nil.  even when I do @shipment.ship_date.to_s it converts it to ""  I know that parameter is not empty as it shows in the web inspector of my browser. I must not know how to work with parameter values.

Comment: This may seem obvious, but are you sure that the value you're expecting to be in the `params` hash is actually there? What does `puts params` look like at this point? Also, is it possible that the key is a string and not a symbol?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be there. Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓" "shipment"=>{"client_id"=>"4", "ship_date"=>"10/24/2012 07:27 pm", "commit"=>"Create Shipment"}

Comment: whether it's a string vs symbol idk.

Comment: Using symbol is fine. But ctilley79, is @shipment suppose to be an instance of Shipment model? 

Then you should create it into a real instance rather than just hash object.

`@shipment = Shipment.new(params[:shipment])`

Comment: @garbagecollection is correct, you need to initialize the `Shipment` instance correctly, using the syntax he/she provided.

Comment: I'm following the basic example of creating a record here.  you're assigning params to a variable then saving them to the database via if @shipment.save!  what I'm trying to do is reformat one of the values so it will correctly save the date in the format I want.

Comment: did you try this? format_date(params["shipment"]["ship_date"])

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev that worked.  feel free to put that in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
format_date(params["shipment"]["ship_date"])
```

should work